# Convert CMS from SOLO version to PRO

Tags: license

I've had to continue with a Craft CMS install somebody else did, now trying to make sense of it.

A client bought a PRO licence, but the CMS seems to still have a SOLO installed. Is there anyway to convert one to another without having down time in the site?

There is no option to upgrade the CMS once you bought the PRO license.

Thanks in advance

Edit: worth noting that clicking "reactivate" results in a "Craft has successfully been upgraded" but does not result in the removal of the "trial" message in the bottom or in added functions.

[image: solo/pro]

Comment: Do you have the config/licence.key file from the install that was upgraded?

Comment: config/license.key is the same as in the CRAFT ID. Checked and reuploaded to make sure.

Answer (score 4):

“Reactivate” is the button you are looking for. Try checking for updates so Craft gets updated license info – the Trial badge sholud go away once Craft realizes that it’s licensed to run Pro. (If not, please contact support@craftcms.com and send in your `config/license.key` file, and we’ll sort it out.)

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my question i've tried this multiple times. 

It seems to work "Craft has been upgraded succesfully" but does not actually convert the install to PRO.

Comment: That’s not expected behavior so please contact support@craftcms.com

Comment: Just went through the same issue and sent an email to support. Change the color of the button and the wording! Maybe just "Activate" or "Activate Pro". I think I saw it quickly, and the word Reactivate made me feel like I had to buy it a second time.

Comment: Unfortunately this issue has not been resolved yet. We are still looking for a solution.

Comment: @het_haasje Have you contacted support@craftcms.com?